# how to append an icon to an AngularStrap $alert?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

is there a way to append an icon to an [AngularStrap $alert](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts#alerts) ?

this is my code

```
    noLinesAlert = $alert({
      container: '.no-lines-alert',
      content: 'no lines at this moment :(',
      dismissable: false,
      show: false,
      title: 'Sorry,',
      type: 'danger'
    })
```

but I do not know if its there a way to do that, or if I have to create a template, in case that I have I would have to create it, how can I do it ?

It seems as if the docs does not provide a full explanation for templates.

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/iWFnx1HtoiRYVj3Oy0NL?p=preview

Comment: you didn't get me, sorry. I mean, I want to append the icon to the alert itself, not the to the button @camden_kid

Answer (score 0):

Create a template with the icon. Here is an example with the font awesome automobile icon :)

alert.template.html :

```html
<div class="alert" ng-class="[type ? 'alert-' + type : null]" style="width:90%;">
  <button type="button" class="close" ng-if="dismissable" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
  <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
  <strong ng-bind="title"></strong>&nbsp;<span ng-bind-html="content"></span>
</div>
```

The angular-strap default alert template is found here -> **https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/alert/alert.tpl.html**. Agree that this should be documented much better.

markup setting `template` to `alert.template.html`  :

```html
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-template="alert.template.html" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" bs-alert="noLinesAlert" data-container=".no-lines-alert">
    alert with icon
</button>
```

[image]

plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/78EH7NInk6AZuJSCpyfZ?p=preview**